# Checking empty and or missing field value in JSON with DataWeave

Tags: json, function, numbers, mule, dataweave

Hi I am transforming JSON to JSON with Dataweave in Mulesoft 3.8.4. I am working with the following lines in JSON (part of a larger file)

```
..
"someField": "12",
"otherField": "5441",
..
```

I want to format 'someField' to a zero left padded string with a total length of 4 (0012). I also want to concat that value to the otherField that also needs to be left padded but with a total length of 6.
To prevent the padding and concatenating to fail I have to check if the field is present, not empty and it has to be numeric.

I have the following code:

```
"My Number": someField as :number as :string {format: "0000"} ++ otherField as :number as :string {format: "0000"}
  when somefield != null
   and someField != ""
   and someField is :number
   and otherField != null
   and otherField != ""
   and otherField is :number
otherwise "",
```

But this fails because 'is :number' returns false because actually the value is a string. Checking something like 'and someField as :number is :number' also fails when the value is empty. What's the best way to check?

Thanx for helping out.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out myself. The part that was mostly in the way was to see if the value was a number. As the node in JSON could be non existing, empty or a text it was difficult to be able to do these tests in one when-otherwise.
What was also a requirement is that there always should be a returning value. So skipping when null was not an option.

Changing the number test into a regex helped. To also make the code more readable I also added some functions that I could also re-use.

The code now looks like this:

```
%function repeat(char, times) (char ++ repeat(char, times - 1)) when times > 0 otherwise ""
%function pad(field, count) field as :number  as :string {format: repeat('0', count)}
%function toNumber(value, count) (pad(value, count)
             when value matches /^\d+$/
        otherwise "")
...
"My Number" : "" when someField == null
   otherwise "" when otherField == null
        otherwise toNumber(someField, 4) ++
                  toNumber(filterUpper(otherField), 6),
...
```

The repeat function gives a string of n-th repeated characters. The pad function left pads my number converted to string with zero's. In this function I use the repeat function to provide the format with the variable zero's string.
The toNumber is a check that see if we only use numbers.

Hope someone else can also benefit from this.